# How do you change the theme based on login in Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm working on a B2B portal using Spartacus where multiple companies can login. We need to show a different theme (scss) depending on what company they are logging in from.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the Box (OOTB), Spartacus does not support changing themes during runtime, and themes are not tied to the user profile either.

Themes can be set dynamically in the back-office ([see documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/storefront-themes/))

Comment: Thanks Saad.
Guess we'll have to implement our own themes based on login groups.

Answer (score 0):

**Spartacus 4.0.1**

For me, I just let backoffice and Spartacus add the theme for me.
i.e.

1. Remove SiteContextConfig from the global config in Angular code (so it can take those properties from backoffice)
2. Set the theme for your site in backoffice e.g. theme: "apples"
3. Spartacus will automatically add the theme class to your app-root

```
<app-root class="apples">
```

After getting the theme class added, I lazy loaded the theme css:

1. lazy load your theme files in *angular.json*

```
    "styles": [
              // standard Spartacus styles
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/page-templates/user.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/page-templates/product.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/page-templates/organization.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/page-templates/checkout.scss",
              // my custom themes
              {
                "input": "src/styles/spartacus/theme-apples.scss",
                "bundleName": "theme-apples",
                "inject": false
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/spartacus/theme-oranges.scss",
                "bundleName": "theme-oranges",
                "inject": false
              }
            ],
```

2. Implement your themes
   e.g. *src/styles/spartacus/theme-apples.scss*

```
@use 'sass:meta';

.apples {
  /* @include so all styles are wrapped inside '.apples' class */
  @include meta.load-css('theme/apples/variables');

  /* fonts */
  @include meta.load-css(
    '../../assets/HelveticNeueLTProBlk/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css'
  );

  /* layout */
  @include meta.load-css('theme/apples/page-templates/homepage');  
  @include meta.load-css('theme/apples/page-templates/product');

}
```

3. Load the CSS files into your head element. Inside of *app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, @Inject(Config) public globalConfig: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.globalConfig.context) {
      if (this.globalConfig.context.theme) {
        this.loadStyle(this.globalConfig.context.theme[0]);
      }
    }
  }

  /* lazy load site specific theme */
  loadStyle(styleName: string) {
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    let themeLink = this.document.getElementById(
      'client-theme'
    ) as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (themeLink) {
      themeLink.href = styleName;
    } else {
      const style = this.document.createElement('link');
      style.id = 'site-theme';
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = `theme-${styleName}.css`;

      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
}
```